How to set MainWindow Icon using CMAKELists.txt and QT6
I am trying to set the MainWindow icon using QT6.
My main.cpp has this:
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QIcon icon(":/Icons/web/favicon.ico");
a.setWindowIcon(icon);

My CMakeLists.txt automatically added this when I added a directory:
if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(MacroPilot
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        oldFunctions.txt
        Icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png Icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png Icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png Icons/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png Icons/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png Icons/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png Icons/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png Icons/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png Icons/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png Icons/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/_/web/ms-application.png Icons/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png Icons/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png Icons/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png Icons/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png Icons/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png Icons/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/Iic_launcher.png Icons/android/playstore-icon.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-20x20@1x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-20x20@2x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-20x20@3x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-29x29@1x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-29x29@2x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-29x29@3x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-40x40@1x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-40x40@2x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-40x40@3x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-60x60@1x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-60x60@2x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-60x60@3x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-76x76@1x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-76x76@2x.png Icons/ios/AppIcons/Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png Icons/ios/appstore.png Icons/ios/iTunesArtwork@1x.png Icons/ios/ItunesArtwork@2x.png Icons/ios/iTunesArtwork@3x.png Icons/web/android-chrome-192x192.png Icons/web/android-chrome-512x512.png Icons/web/apple-touch-icon.png Icons/web/favicon-16x16.png Icons/web/favicon-32x32.png Icons/web/favicon.ico Icons/web/site.webmanifest
    )

My file structure is:


The :/ prefix is used for the Qt resource system. You need to add those icons to the qrc file (normally through Designer) add it to the project and build it accordingly.

Oh okay, that worked. I was getting mixed resources saying that I need to manually edit CMakeLists.txt to include the file path
